# AWS ubuntu machine infected with some kind of miner-gate. How do i diagnose it or get rid of it?

Tags: 14.04, security, hacking, cgminer

I know I can always nuke the instance and start a fresh one. Luckily this is just a test machine. But i'd like to use this opportunity to learn how to diagnose these issues.

In case in matters -  I also have Redis running on this machine.

[screenshot of Top command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnYYZ.png)

Comment: Can you kill the process from the command line (using sudo)?

Comment: Nope. Unable to force kill the process

Comment: This is not a malware. Somebody with root access is running a command to mine for bitcoins using the machine's resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work although I have never had this particular piece of malware:

Close all browsers

sudo kill -9 minergate-cli_pid

sudo apt-get --purge remove minergate-cli

It would be helpful to know which method was used to penetrate your system.  If the process shows up again, run the above commands again and reset all browsers to their default condition.  Do not uninstall and then reinstall them.  The process for doing this varies from browser to browser.

Clamav should see this binary as a virus.  If it persists, type:

sudo clamscan -r --move=/home/USER/QUARANTINE /

This will scan your entire file structure and move any virus found to a folder in your user directory.  Replace USER with your username.